# Using Group By, Count, and Having correctly

Tags: sql

I have a list of categories and items, and I want to return only the categories that have one type of Item.  For instance:

Stuff table:

```
Cat 1 | Item 1
Cat 1 | Item 1
Cat 1 | Item 2
Cat 1 | Item 2
Cat 1 | Item 3
Cat 1 | Item 3
Cat 1 | Item 3
Cat 2 | Item 1
Cat 2 | Item 1
```

I would like to return

```
Cat 2  | Item 1
```

I tried:

```
SELECT category, item
FROM stuff
GROUP BY category, item
HAVING Count(Distinct item) = 1
```

But it's not working.  I returns:

```
Cat 1 | Item 1
Cat 1 | Item 2
Cat 1 | Item 3
Cat 2 | Item 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `item` from your `GROUP BY` clause and run this instead:

```
SELECT category, MAX(item)
FROM stuff
GROUP BY category
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) = 1
```

Example [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1f4aa/1).

Otherwise, each group returned from the `GROUP BY` clause will naturally have exactly one distinct item.

Comment: You're right, I tried it again and it's working great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT category, MAX(item)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY category
HAVING Count(Distinct item) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your database does not allow you to have a variable in the select that is neither in the group by nor aggregated.

Taking advantage that there is only one item, you could try:

```
SELECT category, MIN(item) AS item
FROM stuff
GROUP BY category
HAVING Count(Distinct item) = 1
```